# How to Remove Html Tags  in PHP?

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I use htmlspecialchars function in my string. But, I **don't want** to clean them;

```
<b>, <br>, <p> <ul>,<li> bla bla...
```

Example: `Mystring = "<script>.....</script><br><b>test</b><p>aaaa</p>";`

I want to; =

```
<script>.....</script>
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: I want to convert that all special characters except them tags (<br>, <b> <p> bla bla)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), and especially the [whitelist](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/smoketests/printDefinition.php) feature.

This is probably the safest approach if you allow HTML tags. You can view the comparison [here](http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison).

Answer (score 3):

You want to remove all tags? Use [strip_tags()](http://de.php.net/strip_tags).

Comment: I used it, but <script>, <html>, <head>, <meta> bla blaa... Deleting all of which. I want htmlspecialchars them html tags. (<script>, <html>, <head>, <meta>)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about this function. It's really useful! Thanks. +1

Comment: @henasraf - Yes it's useful, but only if you don't use the second parameter (allowable_tags). Read my comparison link in HTML Purifier.

Answer (score 2):

You can use HTML Sanitizer Class - http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/3746.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use **built in PHP function**: `strip_tags($text, '<p><a><li><b>');`

You don't need to use any class or external library, to remove HTML tags from user input.

In the above example I am cleaning the $text from all tags except `<p><a><li><b>`;

This PHP function will clean user input making sure are not submitting `<script>` or `</div>` to break your page.

Comment: Notably, it will not disallow attributes on allowed tags.